# invoking sed with a shell variable

Tags: bash, shell, variables, sed, expansion

Why doesn't this work?

```
$ s="-e 's/^ *//' -e 's/ *$//'"

$ ls | sed $s
sed: 1: "'s/^
": invalid command code '

$ ls | gsed $s
gsed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

But this does:

```
$ ls | eval sed $s
... prints staff ...

$ ls | eval gsed $s
... prints staff ...
```

Tried removing single quotes from $s but it only works for patterns without spaces:

```
$ s="-e s/a/b/"
$ ls |  sed $s
... prints staff ...

$ s="-e s/^ *//"
$ ls |  sed $s
sed: 1: "s/^
": unterminated substitute pattern
```

or

```
$ s="-e s/^\ *//"
$ ls |  sed $s
sed: 1: "s/^\
": unterminated substitute pattern
```

Mac OS 10.8, bash 4.2, default sed and gsed 4.2.2 from Mac Ports

Comment: In the first case, after the variable is expanded, the single quotes in its value have no special meaning - that is, they are no longer seen as quotes. When you eval it, you're doing a second pass at the expanded string and the single quotes are recognized as significant then.

Comment: Hopefully this is a just a question out of curiosity and you're not actually considering doing that.

Comment: Actually, I am. I am computing patterns on the fly and then using them on a stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple looking question with a complicated answer.  Most of the issue is with the shell; it is only partly a problem with `sed`.  (In other words, you could use a number of different commands instead of `sed` and would run into similar issues.)

Note that most commands documented with an option letter and a separate argument string will also work when the argument string is attached to the option.  For example:

```
sort -t :
sort -t:
```

Both of these give the value `:` to the `-t` option.  Similarly with `sed` and the `-e` option.  That is, you can write either of these:

```
sed -n -e /match/p
sed -n -e/match/p
```

Let's look at the one of the working `sed` commands you wrote:

```
$ s="-e s/a/b/"
$ ls |  sed $s
```

What the `sed` command is passed here is two arguments (after it's command name):

```
-e
s/a/b/
```

This is a perfectly fine set of arguments for `sed`.  What went wrong with the first one, then?

```
$ s="-e 's/^ *//' -e 's/ *$//'"
$ ls | sed $s
```

Well, this time, the `sed` command was passed 6 arguments:

```
-e
's/^
*//'
-e
's/
*$//'
```

You can use the `al` command (argument list — print each argument on its own line; it is described and implemented at the bottom of this answer) to see how arguments are presented to `sed`.  Simply type `al` in place of `sed` in the examples.

Now, the `-e` option should be followed by a valid `sed` command, but `'s/^` is not a valid command; the quote `'` is not a valid `sed` command. When you type the command at the shell prompt, the shell processes the single quote and removes it, so `sed` does not normally see it, but that happens before shell variables are expanded.

Why, then, does the `eval` work:

```
$ s="-e 's/^ *//' -e 's/ *$//'"
$ ls | eval sed $s
```

The `eval` re-evaluates the command line.  It sees:

```
eval sed -e 's/$ *//' -e 's/ *$//'
```

and goes through the full evaluation process.  It removes the single quotes after grouping the characters, so `sed` sees:

```
-e
s/$ *//
-e
s/ *$//
```

which is all completely valid `sed` scripting.

One of your tests was:

```
$ s="-e s/^ *//"
$ ls |  sed $s
```

And this failed because `sed` was given the arguments:

```
-e
s/^
*//
```

The first is not a valid substitute command, and the second is unlikely to be a valid file name.  Interestingly, you could rescue this by putting double quotes around the `$s`, as in:

```
$ s="-e s/^ *//"
$ ls |  sed "$s"
```

Now `sed` gets a single argument:

```
-e s/^ *//
```

but the `-e` can have the command attached, and leading spaces on commands are ignored, so this is all valid.  You can't do that with your first attempt, though:

```
$ s="-e 's/^ *//' -e 's/ *$//'"
$ ls | sed "$s"
```

Now you get told about the `'` not being recognized.  You could, however, have used:

```
$ s="-e s/^ *//; s/ *$//"
$ ls | sed "$s"
```

Again, `sed` sees a single argument, and there are two semicolon-separated `sed` commands in the argument to the `-e` option.

You can ring the variations from here.  I find the `al` command very useful; it quite often helps me understand where something is going wrong.

---

#### Source for `al` — argument list

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    while (*++argv)
        puts(*argv);
    return 0;
}
```

This is one of the smallest useful C programs you can write ('hello world' is one line shorter, but it isn't useful for much beyond demonstrating how to compile and run a program).  It lists each of its arguments on a line on its own.  You can also simulate it in `bash` and other related shells with the `printf` command:

```
printf "%s\n" "$@"
```

Wrap it as a function:

```
al()
{
    printf "%s\n" "$@"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The sed worked for your normal replace pattern because it did not have any metacharacters. You had just a and b. When there are metacharacters involved, you need single quotes.

I think the only way sed would work properly for your variable assignment case is only by using eval.